# Find dependencies of a DTS package in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, ssis, dts

Is there anyway that I can find any dependencies that a DTS package might have?

Comment: Not really. You can use the object model or just text parsing to find things like table and column references but those can change at runtime via expressions or property overrides and you'd have no way of catching that. Something specific you're trying to catch or just an all purpose dependency checker?